# Issue setting up ElasticSearch Index Lifecycle policy with pipeline date index name

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, pipeline, lifecycle, ilm

I'm new to setting up a proper Lifecycle policy, so I'm hoping someone can please give me a hand with this. So, I have an existing index getting created on a weekly basis. This is a third party integration (they provided me with the pipeline and index template for the incoming logs). Logs are being created weekly in the pattern "name-YYYY-MM-DD". I'm attempting to setup a lifecycle policy for these indexes so they transition from hot->warm->delete. So far, I have done the following:

Updated the index template to add the policy and set an alias:

```json
{
  "index": {
    "lifecycle": {
      "name": "Cloudflare",
      "rollover_alias": "cloudflare"
    },
    "mapping": {
      "ignore_malformed": "true"
    },
    "number_of_shards": "1",
    "number_of_replicas": "1"
```

On the existing indexes, set the alias and which one is the "write" index:

```json
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        {
            "add" : {
                 "index" : "cloudflare-2020-07-13",
                 "alias" : "cloudflare",
                 "is_write_index" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}

POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        {
            "add" : {
                 "index" : "cloudflare-2020-07-06",
                 "alias" : "cloudflare",
                 "is_write_index" : false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Once I did that, I started seeing the following 2 errors (1 on each index):

[ILM error #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3KmI.jpg)

[ILM error #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAu0l.jpg)

I'm not sure why the "is not the write index" error is showing up on the older index. Perhaps this is because it is still "hot" and trying to move it to another phase without it being the write index?

For the second error, is this because the name of the index is wrong for rollover?

I'm also not clear if this is a good scenario for rollover. These indexes are being created weekly, which I assume is ok. I would think normally you would create a single index and let the policy split off the older ones based upon your criteria (size, age, etc). Should I change this or can I make this policy work with existing weekly files? In case you need it, here is part of the pipeline that I imported into ElasticSearch that I believe is responsible for the index naming:

```json
{
        "date_index_name" : {
          "field" : "EdgeStartTimestamp",
          "index_name_prefix" : "cloudflare-",
          "date_rounding" : "w",
          "timezone" : "UTC",
          "date_formats" : [
            "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX",
            "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
          ]
        }
      },
```

So, for me at the moment the more important error is the "number_format_exception".  I'm thinking it is due to this setting I'm seeing in the index (provided_name):

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "lifecycle": {
        "name": "Cloudflare",
        "rollover_alias": "cloudflare"
      },
      "mapping": {
        "ignore_malformed": "true"
      },
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "provided_name": "<cloudflare-{2020-07-20||/w{yyyy-MM-dd|UTC}}>",
      "creation_date": "1595203589799",
      "priority": "100",
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
```

I believe this "provided_name" is getting established from the pipeline's "date_index_name" I provided above. If this is the issue, is there a way to create a fixed index name via the ingest pipeline without it changing based upon the date? I would rather just create a fixed index and let the lifecycle policy handle the split offs (i.e. 0001, 0002, etc).

I've been looking for a way to create a fixed index name without the "date_index_name" processor, but I haven't found a way to do this yet.  Or, if I can create an index name with a date and add a suffix that would allow the LifeCycle policy manager (ILM) to add the incremental number at the end, that might work as well.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that the existing indexes [do not end with a sequence number](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html#ilm-gs-bootstrap) (i.e. 0001, 0002, etc), hence the ILM doesn't really know how to proceed.

> The name of this index must match the template’s index pattern and end with a number

You'd be better off letting ILM manage the index creation and rollover, since that's exactly what it's supposed to do. All you need to do is to keep writing to the same `cloudflare` alias and that's it. No need for a `date_index_name` ingest processor.

So your [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html#ilm-gs-apply-policy) is correct as it is.

Next you need to [bootstrap the initial index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html#ilm-gs-bootstrap)

```
PUT cloudflare-2020-08-11-000001
{
  "aliases": {
    "cloudflare": {
      "is_write_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

You can then either [reindex your old indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-with-existing-indices.html#ilm-existing-indices-reindex) into ILM-managed indices or [apply lifecycle policies](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-with-existing-indices.html#ilm-existing-indices-apply) to your old indices.

Comment: Thanks Val.  So, if I'm following you correctly, I just need to remove the entire "date_index_name" processor from the pipeline (so it won't create an index with that naming convention including the date), bootstrap the first index with the name I want ending in -000001, and then as logs hit the pipeline and get ingested, the pipeline will dump the logs into the "cloudflare-2020-08-11-000001" index and the ILM will manage everything at that point?

Comment: That's a security issue, apparently your user `cf-logs` cannot create new indices

Comment: So, I did the above and I'm getting this error:<br/>
index [cloudflare-*], type [_doc], id [null], message [ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=security_exception, reason=action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [cf-logs]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_state_exception, reason=There are no external requests known to support wildcards that don't support replacing their indices]];]<br/>
I basically removed the pipeline, re-created it, and then bootstrapped the initial index.  cf-logs is a superuser.  Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Well as my previous comment stated, you need to review the roles and privileges of cf-logs

Comment: As a super user though, shouldn't this user have all privileges?  I'm using cf-logs to push logs into the pipeline.  I also used this user to create the pipeline initially (and when I re-created it today).  The only difference is that I'm using a different super user to create the bootstrap index (the user I happen to be logged into Kibana with).  Could that be an issue?

Comment: What makes you think that cf-logs is a superuser, what are its roles?

Comment: I don't appear to be able to post a screen shot here in a comment, but that is how this user is setup in Kibana.  The assigned (and only) role is "superuser".

Comment: This is the same user that I've always been using with the previous pipeline that was creating indexes by date using the "date_index_name".

Comment: I'm wondering if the user authorization error is a red herring.  Looking at "reason=There are no external requests known to support wildcards that don't support replacing their indices", this might occur when an index isn't specified during an operation.  I'm wondering if perhaps the pipeline, no longer having any index naming rules, is unable to create or find an existing index now?  Just a guess.

Comment: Just for kicks, I tried switching back to my original config and the logs started flowing again.  With the "date_index_name" processor, indexes are being created weekly at the moment.  So, there doesn't seem to be an issue with the pipeline creating new indexes under this user.  There must be something else going on here.  If you have any other suggestions, I'm all ears :-)